# huawei ascend y530 stuck in recovery screen

Tags: recovery-mode, huawei, huawei-ascend-ii

My phone huawei ascend y530 stuck in recovery screen.  On the screen shows the android icon.I can not turn on phone. Please help me friends.

Comment: We'd love to, but without additional information we can't: What did you do last that might have led to the situation? Is there any error message shown? Are there any other details you could provide?